# Combining robot framework test reports

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, robotframework

We run the robot framework test cases in a certain order and generate a separate output files for each collection. Example is shown below:

pabot -L TRACE --output test1.xml robot_framework/tests/test1

pabot -L TRACE --output test2.xml robot_framework/tests/test2

Later on we use 'rebot' command to combine the test reports as shown below:

rebot test1.xml test2.xml.

The issue we are facing is, there is no output.xml file generated. How can we combine the reports such that there is a 'output.xml' file? If we do not have this file, the Jenkins plugin for Robot Framework fails to generate report.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to add ["--output output.xml"](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#command-line-options-for-post-processing-outputs) to your rebot command line to have the xml file generated:

> rebot --output output.xml test1.xml test2.xml

The Robot Framework Jenkins Plugin can then pick it up.